# Upload Excel contains image file in codeigniter

Tags: excel, codeigniter

I am doing Excel download with codeigniter. Its working, but if I attach an image in an Excel cell, I can't read image from Excel using codeigniter.

[image: My excel sheet image]

```
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel - > getActiveSheet(); foreach($sheetData - > getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    $string = $drawing - > getCoordinates();
    $coordinate = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($string);
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing) {
        echo $filename = $drawing - > getPath();
        $drawing - > getDescription();
        copy($filename, 'http://localhost/fps-update/assets/images/upload_product/'.$datass.
            '.jpg');
    }
}
```

But I am getting error as:

> copy(http://localhost/fps-update/assets/images/upload_product/product_0051.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a mistake while using copy function need to use directory path can not use url.

**use**

```
copy($filename, 'assets/images/upload_product/' . $drawing->getDescription());
```

**instead of --**

```
copy($filename, 'http://localhost/fps-update/assets/images/upload_product/'.$datass.
            '.jpg');
```

please follow this --

http://www.walkswithme.net/reading-images-from-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel

Comment: Ok. Thank you for response. I will try.